# Trying to Use Jenkins Httprequest Plugin for Apk Upload

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, httprequest, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to Upload Apk in Jenkins Build Step. For this I am Using Httprequest plugin, The Problem with this is the content type for APk is : application/vnd.android.package-archive
which is not supported by httprequest plugin.So I downloaded the code and changed the MiMetype to allow the above content type and after building locally I tried uploading the .hpi file directly to jenkins. the problm is it's still sending the contenttype as "multipart/form-data; boundary=dtz9AafOYG6URiP-fHPSliSI_VJxcsNE"

Need some help or suggestion how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting needed format as customHeaders? Like that

```
customHeaders: [[name: 'Content-Type', value: 'type']]
```